# Why do we add salt when precipitating DNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, dna-isolation, lab-techniques

All the DNA extraction protocols I have seen involve adding salts to the extraction buffer. What is the purpose of the salts? What happens if they aren't included?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The role of the salt is to neutralize the charge of the DNA's sugar phosphate backbone.  This makes the DNA less hydrophilic (less soluble in water).

Ethanol has a lower dielectric constant than water so it's used to promote ionic bonds between the Na<sup>+</sup> (from the salt) and the PO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup> (from the DNA backbone) causing the DNA to precipitate.

Comment: since precipitation is one of the methods to purify biomolecules, which separate them from the other components in the solution.